# How to set up a microsoft flow connection to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, connection, power-automate

I am attempting to set up a MS Flow to add data to my SQL Server database.  To set up the Flow Connection there are only six items:

1. Connect via on-premise data gateway
2. Connection Name
3. SQL server Name
4. SQL database Name
5. Username
6. Password

However, when I fill in the appropriate information I get the following error "Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again."

Please note that I can login to my database via SMSS and run queries (e.g. create a table)

Some complexities that are likely affecting the outcome:

(A)  I have to logon to a VPN to my University (with my University ID/Password) before I login to the database via SMSS (with my database Login/Password using SQL Server Authentication).

I have tried to create the connection using all sorts of permutations (e.g. on the VPN vs. off the VPN, University ID vs database ID) but have been unable to find the right combination.

(B)  I not on campus (and rarely am).

(C)  I did not realize until now that there is a **paid** Flow and my University has the **Free** plan.  However, looking at the [features/pricing](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) I should be able to hook up to my SQL Server database.

The error I am getting is both specific but not very helpful as far as giving me any hints on what to change.

With only six options, there is not a lot I can do with the MS Flow.  Is there a setting within the SQL database that I need to change?